# Paint lines over img streaming mjpeg

Tags: html, stream, html5-canvas, draw

I'm trying a simple test using html5. I have a  tag which is connected to a streaming from a camera Axis IP:

```
<img id="stream" class="coveredImage" style="height: 323px;width: 646px;" src="http://192.168.2.65/mjpg/video.mjpg">
```

I see the streaming in the html page. Now I want to paint (lines, rectangles, whatever...) over this element. My doubt is how to do that and if is posible to do it. I think I need a  element to put overlay the  but I'm not sure about this. So I pleased if anyone could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, with simple css:

```
#stream{
 padding-top:10px;
 border-top:1px solid #000;
}
```

and control it with padding